# jboss + spring + webservice : Cannot find ServiceFactory implementation

Tags: spring, jboss

Hi，I use webservice client by spring 3.0.5 , code:

```
    <bean id="helloImpl" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.wtwing.client.HelloImpl" />
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://127.0.0.1:8100/z_axis1.4/services/SayHello?wsdl" />
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://www.wtwing.com/axis/sayHello" />
    <property name="serviceName" value="HelloImplService" />
    <property name="portName" value="SayHello" />
</bean>
```

when tomcat , it's ok, but when jboss 7.1.1 ,error:

```
Failed to initialize service for JAX-RPC port [{http://www.wtwing.com/axis/sayHello}SayHello]; nested exception is javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: Cannot find ServiceFactory implementation
```

Comment: hi you could be missing a JBoss module dependency. Check the modules provided by JBoss in the distribution. If you need to add a dependency many people have posted questions here for the same problem but for a MySQL driver. Hope this helps!